# Getting random unrelated API responses from OpenAI text-davinci-003

Tags: node.js, nlp, openai-api

I'm running a Node script, using Axios to pull a web page from eater.com, then using Cheerio to parse the DOM and pull out the text. I have a prompt I'm feeding to Open AI that works perfectly in the Playground.

When I run it through the API via my script, though, each time **I get a completely coherent but completely unrelated (and random) reply**. I've gotten album announcements, a random piece of Swift code, etc. IT SEEMS COMPLETELY RANDOM.

My prompt is here: https://beta.openai.com/playground/p/N0Hw1Btcu8g70utQu2lO4pKD?model=text-davinci-003

If I run this in the playground, it gives great results!

Here's the script (which is successfully generating the prompt): https://replit.com/@JDMaresco/GenerousDisguisedLinks#index.js

> (You'd need to `npm install`, add OpenAI env variables / secrets, and then `node index.js` in the shell to run this)

It's returning results as absurd as

```
[
    {
        "text": "In a world of ever-increasing competition, Branding is the key to success.\n\nBranding is the process of creating a unique image or identity for a product, service, or company. It is a way of distinguishing one company or product from another in the minds of consumers. Branding is essential in today’s world as it helps businesses stand out from the competition and gain an edge in the marketplace. A good brand can create a lasting impression on customers, differentiate a product or service from its competitors, and increase customer loyalty. It also serves to create an emotional connection between customers and the brand. Branding can help a business build a strong reputation, increase customer loyalty, and generate more revenue. It is also an important tool for communicating a company’s values and mission. Branding can also be used to increase credibility and trust in a company’s products and services. It can help a company establish a presence in a particular market and create a sense of familiarity with customers.",
        "index": 0,
        "logprobs": null,
        "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
]
```

any idea what's happening?

Comment: Ok .... I had a stupid code error and was passing a `null` to the OpenAI prompt. 

I'm still very surprised that this causes the AI to return a completely random paragraph-long response, rather than an error. Would love to hear if anyone has an answer on this!!!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to share your progress and state your current inquire. Also, I think that you should add a [mcve] direclty into the question body.